# How to share up-to-date global context between Container app and micro-frontend app?

Tags: reactjs, webpack-module-federation

I am using webpack module federation plugin, and there are **Container** and **Micro frontend** apps (both are written on React). Based on the new requirement I should implement an authentication logic using a third-party service Auth0 and `@auth0/auth0-react` package.

This package uses context and provider to share the data (user information, token etc.) across components tree, so I wrapped my **Container** app with auth provider:

```
<Auth0Provider
  domain={domain}
  clientId={clientId}
  redirectUri={window.location.origin}
  onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}
>
  {children}
</Auth0Provider>
```

to access auth data anywhere in the components tree we can use `useAuth0` hook:

```
  import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react';
  const {
    isLoading,
    isAuthenticated,
    error,
    user,
    loginWithRedirect,
    logout,
  } = useAuth0();
```

Now, I am stuck, how can I access the up-to-date auth data/context in my micro frontends? Note: the auth context of the **Container** app will be updated asynchronously (after the '/token' request will be completed)

From what I've tried is to share `AuthProvider` as a service with my micro-frontend:

**Container app** webpack config:

```
name: 'container',
exposes: {
  './App': './src/App',
  './AuthenticationProvider': './src/AuthenticationProvider',
},
```

**Micro front end app** webpack config:

```
remotes: {
  container: 'container@http://localhost:8080/remoteEntry.js',
},
```

and then
`import { AuthenticationProvider } from 'container/AuthenticationProvider';`
in my micro-frontend app.

Of course, it doesn't work as expected and the up-to-data will be in the **Container** application only.

The question is: How can I access the up-to-date context from the Container app in the micro-frontend app? Should I use some pub/sub system to notify my Micro frontend app about auth changes in the Container app? I would appreciate any ideas. thanks!

Comment: Hi Did you get any solutions for this?